# PHP: Convert array format to another format

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array output like :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 25-08-2014
    [1] => 26-08-2014
    [2] => 27-08-2014
    [3] => 28-08-2014
)
```

I need to convert it like :-

```
$duration = array("25/08/2014", "26/08/2014", "27/08/2014");
```

I try to use it in this function :-

```
if (in_array($dateOutput, $duration))
```

How can i do that?

Comment: as @RST you need to post what you have tried and not expect us to do this for you

Comment: i try to use it in this condition  `(in_array($dateOutput, $duration))`

Comment: 1. Loop. 2. Either parse the date and reformat it, or simply replace `-` to `/`. This is a trivial exercise. `in_array` has nothing to do with what you're asking.

Comment: there is no reformatting in in_array(), did you read the documentation on that command? It only checks whether or not some value is present in a given array. What did you try to change the values.

Comment: @deceze can you explain your solution by code ?!!

Comment: @RST, So what can i do to check this array result by using "in_array"

Comment: take a look at PHP str_replace command to start with, although array_walk will probably be better.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `in_array` in the first place?

Comment: In your previous question, didn't you use `$dateAry[]=$dateObj->format($format);`? (where `$format` is `d/m/Y`). Why are you trying to convert it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although (as many commenters have said), you should have shown what you tried. See a solution below:

```
$arr = array(
    "25-08-2014", 
    "26-08-2014", 
    "27-08-2014"
);
function reformat($date_string)
{
    return str_replace('/', '-', $date_string);
}
$arr_editted = array_map('reformat', $arr);
```

This will give you your desired value. You can use anonymous functions with `array_map` as well; but since I'm not sure of your PHP version, you should use this.

[PHP array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you want is to change the `-` to `/`?

Then you could use this:

```
<?php
$dates = array("25-08-2014", "26-08-2014", "27-08-2014");
$total = count($dates);
for( $i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
     $dates[$i] = str_replace( '-', '/', $dates[$i] );
}
print_r( $dates );
?>
```

An alternative is to use the [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/array_map) function:

```
<?php
function swapIt($value) {
    return str_replace( '-', '/', $value );
}

$dates = array("25-08-2014", "26-08-2014", "27-08-2014");
$newDates = array_map( "swapIt", $dates );
print_r( $newDates );
?>
```

Comment: please don't use count or length in a for loop when the array length is not going to change inside the loop. Put the value in a variable and use that. There is no need to perform the same calculation over and over. It will make a difference on large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
$dateOutputs = array("25-08-2014", "26-08-2014", "27-08-2014", "28-08-2014");
$duration = array("25/08/2014", "26/08/2014", "27/08/2014");

foreach ($dateOutputs as $dateOutput) {
    $neededDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dateOutput));
    if (in_array($neededDate, $duration)) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.